# Have element on top of canvas without pushing canvas down -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, slider

So I have a simple javascript that bounces a ball up and down on a canvas that takes up the whole screen. I want to add simple value sliders in at the top of the screen. The problem is when I create them they position themselves on top of the canvas and push the canvas down. So basically There is now scroll bars that I don't want, and you can't see the whole ball animation and the sliders at the same time (without zooming out). How can I have these sliders without causing the need for scroll bars.

Here is all my code that initializes the canvas

```
<canvas></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    var H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

</script>
```

Here is my code that creates a slider

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function showValue(newValue){
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }

</script>
```

You can view a working example without the slider [here](http://tysonsmith.info/gravity/noslider.html). I basically want this exact page but with a slider on top.

You can view a working example with the slider [here](http://tysonsmith.info/gravity/slider.html). You can see how the scroll bars are annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x0cr3ofk/

if you position your elements absolute you are able to stack them.

I added some css to your code that helps get rid of the scrollbars:

```
.stacked_slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 1px;  
    z-index: 7;
}

.canvas_class {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" class="stacked_slider"/>
<span id="range">0</span>
<canvas class="canvas_class">    
</canvas>
```

no changes to your JS necessary